# Не видит загрузочной флешки с Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

Решил установить Ubuntu второй ОС.
Скачал образ и установил его на флешку. Память для будущей Ubuntu выделил ещё когда устанавливал Windows.
Проблема в том, что когда нажимаю <kbd>F9</kbd> (Boot Device Options) и выбираю флешку, выдает ошибку:

> "An operating system wasnt found. Try disconnecting any drivers that dont contain an operating system"

Гуглил, не помогло.
У кого такое было и что с этим делать?

[image: BIOS]

---

Весело, однако, но записав Rufus'ом всё запустилось с первого раза

Comment: Что такое "вижити"?

Comment: @llenn поправил, спасибо

Comment: Скорее всего, у Вас проблема во включенной опции UEFI BIOS `Secure boot`, которая позволяет грузиться только с windows. Поскольку Вы не уточнили тип Вашего устройства (модель ноута или системной платы), то могу предложить только общие рекомендации - отключить эту опцию в BIOS'е. И, может быть, поможет обзор разных вариантов: https://remontka.pro/secure-boot-disable/

Comment: @Vladimir 
Да, знате, похоже вы правы: ноутбук hp 255 g6
Купил пару дней назад и там был листочек от производителя на котором на куче языков было написано, что на этом устройсве не поддерживается Windows 7 или  Windows 8, а именно, что компания HP не поставляет драйвера под эти ОС.

Comment: UPD: Secure Boot отключена и изменить это нельзя(неактивно)

Comment: Что-то в Ваших словах не сходится. Вы не могли бы прикрепить к вопросу фотографию BIOS, с окном, где есть пункт Secure boot. Просто, если она не активна, то тогда у Вас может быть включен режим загрузки Legacy. Но тогда с флешки спокойно должно было загрузиться (как в ответах уже писали, современные загрузочные образы Ubuntu имеют гибридный загрузчик и должны работать и с UEFI, и со старым вариантом загрузки). А неподдержка драйверов для Windows 7/8 в данном деле не имеет значения. Вам же нужен Linux.

Comment: @Vladimir прикрепил. Всё, что в черном цвете менять нельзя, в том числе и Secure boot

Comment: Да, это как раз то, о чем я говорил. У вас сейчас включен Legacy режим. И это значит, что должен использоваться старый вариант загрузки, без всяких UEFI. И при этом, у Вас Windows 10 нормально загружается? В смысле, установлен тоже в этом режиме, а не в UEFI?

Comment: @Vladimir да, Windows 10 загружается нормально, без заскоков. В этом же, походу

Comment: Тогда странно, что на флешке не нашелся загрузчик... Попробуйте использовать другую программу для записи образа (мне больше нравится `rufus` - он позволяет выбрать каким делать загрузчик; так же, можно попробовать разные варианты MBR/GPT с BIOS). А если и это не поможет, то еще можно взять другую флешку, ибо был и такой опыт.

Comment: @Vladimir, хорошо, позже попробую. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @LLEN, вчить мову вже! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если в настройках порядка загрузки ОС в BIOS материнской платы первым в списке идет HDD, на котором нет ОС, то другие источники рассматриваются уже не будут. HDD имеет смысл передвинуть в конец списка.
2. Есть два варианта загрузки ОС в BIOS материнской платы:

   - Общепринятый и активно используемый на большинстве современных компьютеров.
   - [UEFI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) - новый стандарт, изначально разработанный компанией Intel.

     Между собой они не совместимы, т.е. ОС с поддержкой только UEFI не будет загружаться на компьютерах без соответствующей поддержки и наоборот.

     На некоторых материнских платах есть возможность переключать эти интерфейсы между собой, устанавливая порядок загрузки ОС с различных носителей.

     Последние дистрибутивы `Ubuntu` поддерживают оба варианта загрузки (загрузчик выглядит чуть-чуть иначе).
3. Если загрузчик ОС на материнской плате ни в какую не хочет видеть флешку - возможно образ `*.iso` был записан криво. Причины:

   - Некорректно был скачан сам файл `*.iso`
   - Файл `*.iso` был некорректно записан на `USB` носитель.

     Для корректной записи образов дисков `*.iso` лучше использовать ИМХО nix-утилиту `dd`, но есть и другие программы.

Comment: 1. Я не могу изменить порядок в списке(в F10 вообще нету вкладки Boot). В F9 предлагает выбрать устройство с которого  нужно загрузиться: жёсткий диск там идёт первым и передвинуть его нельзя.Там активные действия: вверх, вниз, enter.Когда выбыраю флешку вылезает ошибка.Когда вставляю другую флешку с Виндоус 10 и опять выбираю её, то начинается загрузка Windows. С Ubuntu так работать не хочет

Comment: wmic baseboard get product выдает 8330. Ноутбук HP 255 G6 (2EW01ES)

Comment: ок, попробую поставить на виртуальную машину. dd - это же команда в unix, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score -3):

У меня такое было, и не раз. Это говорит о том, что флешка записалась криво, или вообще не записалась.

Для нормального создания загрузочных флешек, используйте утилиту `dd`, и только `dd`, и ничего кроме `dd`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84431/discussion-between-andreymal-and-drakonoved).

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto я не знаю, что изменилось сегодня, но у меня всё стало загружаться на всех доступных мне компьютерах. У меня всё же где-то кривые руки, но я так и не понял где (я использовал dd точно так же, как и когда он у меня не работал). Но теперь сайт не даёт мне убрать минус, требуя правки ответа. Всё же допишите в ответ, что iso-образ обязательно должен быть **isohybrid** (простые образы дисков не будут загружаться с UEFI, просто потому что в них нет загрузочного раздела UEFI), и я поменяю минус на плюс

Comment: @Drakonoved вам пришло уведомление об этом комментарии?